# Create jnilib from x86_64 .a files on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: java, c, static, dylib, libtool-xcode

I want to use a bunch of non-universal (thin?), x86_64, C libraries from a Java application.
The problem is that I only have static versions of them (.a files) and the jvm needs them to be dynamic.

I tried using libtool to combine the files into a single dynamic library but I just got error messages saying that many of the symbols (possibly all, there are many) are missing for x86_64, which is strange because I have no problems making a small C application with -arch x86_64 using some of the libraries and get it to link and run correctly.

This should be a simple command line thing right? The last thing I want is to write my own wrapper functions for already existing functions just so I can get them into a dynamic library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to modify the build scripts for the libs in question to make dylibs for me in addition to the static libs so it's not an issue any more.